# oledbdataadapter command builder getupdate, needs key for argument

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, refresh, oledbdataadapter

I seem to be having an issue. I have a `dataset` (excel) sourced to a `datagridview` in a windows forms application. I'm hoping to find a way to refresh/update my `dataset` within the `datagridview` after making a change to a cell.

Let me go through the steps I've taken to try and accomplish this. I've added a "refresh" `button` to the form and I've created a method called `write2DGV` which will write changes to the `dataset` after changes are made in the `datagridview`.

I've added a timer that will allow Excel to update to update the outputs. I've also added code to wipe clean my `dataset` (which is the datasource for the `datagridview`). Last I have a retrieve method that will source the `dataset` to the `datagridview` via the `oledataadapter`.

Unfortunately when I run the code **I get an error message about not providing a key as an argument to the get update method**. I'm not exactly sure what they mean by "key", also the only valid  data types for the argument to the get update method is boolean. My code is below:

```
'Declarations
Dim myDataSet As DataSet
Dim MyCommand As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim objWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = objExcel.ActiveSheet
Dim sizetimer As New System.Timers.Timer

Sub retrieveMyDataSet()
    MyCommand = New OleDbDataAdapter(select * from [MyExcelWorksheet$A13:x150], MyConnection)
     myDataSet = New System.Data.DataSet()
    MyCommand.Fill(myDataSet)
    myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0).DefaultView
End Sub

Sub write2Size()
    'A-k gets written.  Entire graph goes to a-x so I only need to writ the columncount -14
   'x is letter 24. k is letter 11.  24-11 = 13.  So, offset needs to be -13
   '39;Rows 13 through first blank
        Dim rowindex As Integer
        Dim columnindex As Integer
        For rowindex = 1 To myDataGridView.RowCount
        For columnindex = 1 To myDataGridView.ColumnCount - 13
            objWorkSheet.Cells(rowindex + 13, columnindex + 0) = myDataGridView(columnindex     - 1, rowindex - 1).Value
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Sub refreshDGV()
    write2DGV()
    myDataSet.Clear()
    Dim x As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [MyExcelWorksheet$A13:x150]", MyConnection)
    Dim oledbCommands As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(x)
    x.UpdateCommand = oledbCommands.GetUpdateCommand() 'oops type! removed = x.UpdateCommand
    x.Update(myDataSet)
    sizetimer.AutoReset = True
    sizetimer.Interval = 2000 '2 seconds
    retrieveMyDataSet()
End Sub

Private Sub refreshbtn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles refreshbtnSize.Click
   refreshDGV()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately when I run the code I get an error message about not
>   providing a key as an argument to the get update method.

The reason of this error is explained in this article that you should read carrefully: [**How To Use ADO.NET to Retrieve and Modify Records in an Excel Workbook With Visual Basic .NET**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934/en-us)

You are using one of the solution mentionned in this article to update the worksheet, ie *Make changes to a DataSet that you have filled with a table/query from an Excel workbook and then call the Update method of the DataAdapter to resolve changes from the DataSet back to the workbook.*

But just after we can read:

> However, to use the Update method for change resolution you must set
>   parameterized commands for the DataAdapter's InsertCommand

```
INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (F1, F2) values (?, ?)
```

> and UpdateCommand:

```
UPDATE [Sheet1$]SET F2 = ? WHERE F1 = ?
```

> **Parameterized INSERT and UPDATE commands are
>   required because the OleDbDataAdapter does not supply key/index
>   information for Excel workbooks; without key/index fields, the
>   CommandBuilder cannot automatically generate the commands for you.**

The message is clear: you have to explicitly write parameterized `INSERT` and `UPDATE` commands if you want achieve what you are trying to do.

And don't forget that Excel has a lot a functionnality **but is not especially designed to work as a database**. So to avoid a lot of problems, I recommand you to switch to another local database (SqlServerCompact, SQlLite, ...).